# Creating stored procedure for multiple insert and alter table queries

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

```
$link->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2");           
$link->query("CREATE TABLE table2 (newcol BIGINT UNSIGNED  PRIMARY KEY)");
$result=$link->query("select col1 from table1");
while($data=$result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    $link->query("insert into table2 (newcol) values($data['col1']);
    $link->query(""ALTER TABLE table2 ADD  `".$data['col1']."` BIGINT DEFAULT 0"");
  }
```

What Iam trying to do is

1. Create a table "`table2`" with one column "`newcol`".
2. select all the values of "`col1`" from  "`table1`" And
3. for each value of `col1` from `table1`

   -insert the value into "`newcol`" of `table2` And

   -add a column `named` (`value` from `col1` of `table 1`) into "`table2`"

> The above code looks very neat and efficient in php , but the problem is it takes some amount of time .So I think its better to convert these into MySQL Stored procedure .Since I'm new to stored procedures , very much confused .Please help me guys.

Comment: Will the tables and the fields always be the same or do you intend to pass those value as input in your stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jonathan Parent Lévesque**  helped me a lot in figuring out how the looping inside stored procedures work and to get the overall structure for the stored procedure equivalent to the php code described in the question above.
Thanks **Jonathan Parent Lévesque**

But in his code Adding column name using a variable didn't work as expected.

> Finally I figured it out

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE _done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE _myField BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

    DEClARE _myReader CURSOR FOR
    SELECT id FROM `tags`;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET _done = TRUE;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tag_similarity`;

    CREATE TABLE `tag_similarity` (
        `tag` BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
    );

    OPEN _myReader;

    myLoop: LOOP

        FETCH _myReader INTO _myField;

        IF _done = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE myLoop;
        END IF;


        INSERT INTO `tag_similarity` (tag) VALUES (_myField);
        SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE tag_similarity ADD `',_myfield,'` BIGINT DEFAULT 0');
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
         EXECUTE stmt ;
         DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
      END LOOP myLoop;

    CLOSE _myReader;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I couldn't test it, but it is compiling fine on on my computer.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `myProcedure` ()
BEGIN

    DECLARE _done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE _myField BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

    /* the cursor here is like your PDOStatement 
    * it is used to fetch data */
    DEClARE _myReader CURSOR FOR
        SELECT `col1` FROM `table1`;

    /* it is not very elegant, but we need to throw an exception
    * to break the loop */    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET _done = TRUE;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table2`;

    CREATE TABLE `table2` (
        `newcol` BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
    );

    /* you open your PDOStatement */
    OPEN _myReader;

    /* myLoop is like a GOTO*/
    myLoop: LOOP

        /* $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)*/
        FETCH _myReader INTO _myField;

        /* if the no data exception had been thrown, 
        * goto the end of the loop */
        IF _done = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE myLoop;
        END IF;


        INSERT INTO `table2` (newcol) VALUES (_myField);

        ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD `_myField` BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

    END LOOP myLoop;

    /* close your PDO object */     
    CLOSE _myReader;

END //
```

Comment: I will test it soon . Can you add some commented details for each statements ,since it will be useful for me and others who are new to this stored procedures . Its hard to find simple examples on various operations like using cursors in  stored procedures for learning purpose.

Comment: much better  now , have a doubt , is there any alternate for achieving this with out using cursors ?

Comment: If it was just inserting, I would have done something like `INSERT INTO table2 (newcol) SELECT col1 FROM table1`, but you also need to alter the table two to create the new field. I think the current solution is probably the simplest.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table2 (newcol) SELECT col1 FROM table1`.